# CSS nth-child - get 1st, 2nd, 4th and 5th children at once?

Tags: css, css-selectors

With CSS3 I know I can use the `nth-child(an + b)` selector. I have a table with 5 rows and I would like to select the 1st, 2nd, 4th and 5th rows with one statement.  Is this possible or do I have to use a minimum of two statements like this:

```
:nth-child(-n+2)  /* gets 1 and 2 */
:nth-child(n+4)   /* gets 4 and 5 */
```

I was hoping for a syntax like `nth-child(1,2,4,5)` or `nth-child(1-2,4-5)` but it doesn't appear to be part of the spec.

(I have no control over the page and there are no IDs/classes on these rows.)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If you want to be explicit, one way is to repeat `:nth-child()` like so:

```
tr:nth-child(1), tr:nth-child(2), tr:nth-child(4), tr:nth-child(5)
```

Alternately, since the table happens to have exactly 5 rows, you can just exclude the third row and you'll get rows #1, #2, #4 and #5:

```
tr:not(:nth-child(3))
```

[jsFiddle preview](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/f2vFx)

Answer (score 3):

To make it the more generic possible you can use this:

```
tr:not(:nth-child(1n+6)):not(:nth-child(3))  { 
    /* your rules here */
}
```

To explain it a little:
you are saying you want to select the elements that are ***not*** from 6 on (so the first 5) ***and not*** 3rd, if you wrote

```
 tr:nth-child(1n+6)
```

you were targeting the rows from 5 on, since you were selecting the rows

(1*0) + 6    [ = 6 ]

(1*1) + 6    [ = 7 ]

(1*2) + 6    [ = 8 ]

...and so on. This is what it means the expression (1n+X), where X in our case is 6.

Adding the :not pseudo selector to the expression above, you are saying you want to select the rows which are ***not*** from 5 on, so you will select from 5 down, the 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th and  5th.

Plus, adding one more :not selector, which targets the 3rd, you will get what you want => The first 5 without the 3rd!

/***************** UPDATED! I added a jsfiddle *******************/

Here you can see it working in this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/adrisimo74/9jd9ox62/)

Answer (score 1):

You can always use even and odd keywords
Like:

table tr:nth-child(even) or if you want the table data use table td:nth-child(odd)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the `:is` notation if you're using a lot of parents. This is not necessarily a better way, but just looks a bit better imo.

So instead of

```
.wrapper-class .another-class tr:nth-child(1), 
.wrapper-class .another-class tr:nth-child(2), 
.wrapper-class .another-class tr:nth-child(4), 
.wrapper-class .another-class tr:nth-child(5) {}
```

You get

```
.wrapper-class .another-class tr:is(:nth-child(1),:nth-child(2),:nth-child(4),:nth-child(5)) {}
```